# Manage Offline Network Installation of Visual Studio 2017

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017

Since Visual Studio moved to a more evergreen approach with VS2017, I have downloaded an offline copy via instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio) to make available on a network share for installation across many computers in my organization.  The first download which contained all installation options was sized at 25GB.  Whenever a new update is released, I re-run my download script

```
vs_Professional.exe --layout I:\vs2017offline --lang en-US
```

And it goes through all the packages, verifying most and for ones that have changed it downloads new.  This works great but the total size on disk now has ballooned to more than 80GB after almost a year of "keeping up" with the updates.

My question is how best to manage this offline installation.  Basically I want to make use of keeping unchanged installation files but do not want to keep the superseded/outdated files and definitely do not want to have to re-download the complete set every time a new update is released.  Is there a command or strategy that can be used to remove the old installation files from the network download?

Comment: There should be documented instructions to remove components from the installation, have you tried that?

Comment: Here: did the work for you https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio#how-to-remove-older-versions-from-a-layout on a phone don’t feel like submitting an answer